# Phoenix table split by composite row key

Tags: apache-phoenix

Is it possible to specify region split values when creating a table in Phoenix with composite primary key? For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(A VARCHAR, B VARCHAR CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (A,B)) SPLIT ON (1,2)
```

The above specifies the value for splitting on key `A`. How do include a value for `B` i.e. I want to split using keys. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be undocumented, but it works if you nest the split points.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(A VARCHAR, B VARCHAR CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (A,B)) 
SPLIT ON (('1', '2'), ('3', '4'))
```